# How much of jasmine should be included in version control?

Tags: git, version-control, jasmine

I have a jQuery plugin in it's own git repository that I'm going to make open source. The automated tests have been written using the Jasmine framework.

I'm aware that it is considered good practise to only include project specific code within version control. So for my automated tests I'd ideally like to only include the test definitions from the `spec` directory, however in order for the test suite to run developers need the Jasmine `SpecRunner.html` and the `lib` directory (which contains Jasmine libraries only).

What's the best practice here? Should I check in everything required for the test suite to run, or only the specs themselves? Is there an elegant solution via `package.json` or something similar that I'm missing?

Here's the directory structure for reference:

```
 .
 ├── Gruntfile.js
 ├── README.md
 ├── SpecRunner.html
 ├── demo
 ├── dist
 ├── lib
     ├── jasmine-1.3.1
     ├── jasmine-jquery-1.5.8.js
     └── jquery-1.10.2.js
 ├── node_modules
 ├── package.json
 ├── spec
 └── src
```

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I would only use the specifications to give a sense of organization and code clean, elegant solution you seek would be to use Maven to manage the dependencies and libraries, not only from jQuery to have a repository for easy access and scalable thinking about reuse.